# Understanding the architecture of an LSTM for sequence classification

Tags: pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have this model in pytorch that I have been using for sequence classification.

```
class RoBERT_Model(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, hidden_size = 100):
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        super(RoBERT_Model, self).__init__()
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(768, hidden_size, num_layers=1, bidirectional=False)
        self.out = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 2)

    def forward(self, grouped_pooled_outs):
        # chunks_emb = pooled_out.split_with_sizes(lengt) # splits the input tensor into a list of tensors where the length of each sublist is determined by length

        seq_lengths = torch.LongTensor([x for x in map(len, grouped_pooled_outs)]) # gets the length of each sublist in chunks_emb and returns it as an array

        batch_emb_pad = nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence(grouped_pooled_outs, padding_value=-91, batch_first=True) # pads each sublist in chunks_emb to the largest sublist with value -91
        batch_emb = batch_emb_pad.transpose(0, 1)  # (B,L,D) -> (L,B,D)
        lstm_input = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(batch_emb, seq_lengths, batch_first=False, enforce_sorted=False) # seq_lengths.cpu().numpy()

        packed_output, (h_t, h_c) = self.lstm(lstm_input, )  # (h_t, h_c))
        # output, _ = nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(packed_output, padding_value=-91)
        h_t = h_t.view(-1, self.hidden_size) # (-1, 100)

        return self.out(h_t) # logits
```

The issue that I am having is that I am not entirely convinced of what data is being passed to the final classification layer. I believe what is being done is that only the final LSTM cell in the last layer is being used for classification. That is there are `hidden_size` features that are passed to the feedforward layer.

I have depicted what I believe is going on in this figure here:

[image]

Is this understanding correct? Am I missing anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a basic LSTM for classification, working with a single rnn layer.

In your picture you have multiple LSTM layers, while, in reality, there is only one, `H_n^0` in the picture.

1. Your input to LSTM is of shape `(B, L, D)` as correctly pointed out in the comment.
2. `packed_output` and `h_c` is not used at all, hence you can change this line to: `_, (h_t, _) = self.lstm(lstm_input)` in order no to clutter the picture further
3. `h_t` is **output of last step for each batch element**, in general `(B, D * L, hidden_size)`. As this neural network **is not bidirectional** `D=1`, as you have a single layer `L=1` as well, hence the output is of shape `(B, 1, hidden_size)`.
4. This output is reshaped into `nn.Linear` compatible (this line: `h_t = h_t.view(-1, self.hidden_size)`) and will give you output of shape `(B, hidden_size)`
5. This input is fed to a single `nn.Linear` layer.

In general, the output of the last time step from RNN is used for each element in the batch, in your picture `H_n^0` and simply fed to the classifier.

By the way, having `self.out = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 2)` in classification is probably counter-productive; most likely your are performing binary classification and `self.out = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 1)` with [`torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html) might be used. Single logit contains information whether the label should be `0` or `1`; everything smaller than `0` is more likely to be `0` according to nn, everything above `0` is considered as a `1` label.

Comment: Sorry the photo / code pair may have been misleading a bit. The dashed lines were supposed to represent that there could be 1 to (W-1) number of layers. So just to clarify, suppose I was using 5 lstm layers. This would mean that just `H_n^4` would be (and should be) fed to the classifier, correct?

Comment: Also thanks for the note about using just 1 neuron for binary classification. As a side question to that, in general for n-ary classification where n > 2, we should have n output neurons, right?

Comment: @LucaGuarro Yes, the last layer H_n^4 should be fed in this case (although it would require some code changes, check docs for exact description of the outputs). Side question - yes, for multiclass you would use CrossEntropy, for multilabel BCE, but still n outputs.